# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, es6-promise

I am trying to map through an array of coordinates and place a Marker on each coordinate in Google Maps, but I get this error:

*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

So it's returning an array of Promises. I am not sure how to go about making it so that it returns the actual values.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from "google-maps-react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {getVacations} from "./redux";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

    }

       componentDidMount = () => {
           this.props.getVacations();
       }

       render() {
        console.log(this.props);

        const coordinates = this.props.vacations.map(coordinate => {
            const convert = Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location).then(response => {
                const lat = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                const lng = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                console.log(lat, lng);
                return <Marker key={coordinate._id} position={{lat: lat, lng: lng}} animation={2}/>
            })   
            console.log(convert);
            return convert;
         })


         return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={4}>
                    {coordinates}
                </Map>
            </div>
        )
       }
    }

    const connectVaca = connect(state => ({vacations: state}), {getVacations})(GoogleMaps);

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: "API KEY HERE"
})(connectVaca)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *coordinates* is an array of Promises. At the statement below:

`const convert = Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location)then(...)`

you just creating a promise object `convert` and returning in map.You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get the actual values and put the result into the state. First change constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { coords: [] }
}
```

Get values for all promises:

```
const coordinates = this.props.vacations.map(coordinate => {
      const convert = Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location)
      return convert;
})

Promise.all(coordinates).then(values => {
  //Create your markers array here and put into state
  const markers = values.map(item => ... )
  this.setState({ coords: markers })
});
```

Then use `this.state.coords` in returned jsx object.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={4}>
            {this.state.coords}
        </Map>
    </div>
)
```

This should work.

Comment: Ok, so this didn't work, but I'm like 95% sure I'm not doing it the right way.

Inside of `markers` in the `values.map` am I suppose to put this:

`const lat = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                const lng = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                console.log(lat, lng);
                return <Marker key={coordinate._id} position={{lat: lat, lng: lng}} animation={2}/>`

I am pretty sure I am not but that's what I did. @IsmayilNiftaliyev